# HTTP failure response for my web site unauthorized -401 error

Tags: iis, iis-10

I just deployed my web site to our internal production server. I enabled the windows authentication for my web site. below is the screen shot:

After doing that, I tried to run my application and I got below error in developers tool:

This web site runs fine on our internal staging server with the same authentication.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's exactly Windows authentication, https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221693 If your initial HTTP request does not carry user credentials (preauthenticate), then a 401 response is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below link in case you missed the IIS Settings same as your localhost. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/understanding-windows-authentication-in-detail/

Also, 
Your Server does not know the users of your local windows until you are connected via active directory. Production and your PC should share the same domain.

Make sure to read the Microsoft official guide for Windows Authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

[Windows Authentication critera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOel1.png)